# Matlab: Dealing with denorm performance cost conversion when close to realmin in backprop

Tags: matlab, neural-network, precision, backpropagation, gradient-descent

I understand that if a number gets closer to zero than `realmin`, then Matlab converts the double to a [denorm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denormal_number) . I am noticing this causes significant performance cost. In particular I am using a gradient descent algorithm that when near convergence, the gradients (in backprop for my bespoke neural network) drop below `realmin` such that the algorithm incurs heavy performance cost (due to, I am assuming, type conversion behind the scenes). I have used the following code to validate my gradient matrices so that no numbers falls below `realmin`:

`function mat= validateSmallDoubles(obj, mat, threshold)
            mat= mat.*(abs(mat)>threshold);
 end`

Is this usual practice and what value should `threshold` take (obviously you want this as close to `realmin` as possible, but not too close otherwise any additional division operations will send some elements of `mat` below `realmin` *after* validation)?. Also, specifically for neural networks, where are the best places to do gradient validation without ruining the network's ability to learn?. I would be grateful to know what solutions people with experience in training neural networks have? I am sure this is a problem for all languages. Tentative `threshold` values have ruined my network's learning.

Comment: Same question on cross validated:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/336033/matlab-dealing-with-denorm-performance-cost-conversion-when-close-to-realmin-fo

Comment: I'm also aware that ReLU activation functions and appropriate weight initialisation mitigate vanishing gradients, but is there validation in the code to prevent this from happening if it does for some reason occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I traced the diminishing gradient occurrences to the Adam SGD optimiser - the biased moving average matrix calculations in the Adam optimiser were causing matlab to carry out the denorm operation. I simply thresholded the matrix elements for each layer after these calculations, with `threshold=10*realmin`, to zero without any effect on learning. I have yet to investigate why my moving averages were getting so close to zero as my architecture and weight initialisation priors would normally mitigate this.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it is somehow related to your problem, but I had a similar problem with underflows while doing exponentially weighted average of gradients (say while implementing Momentum or Adam).

In particular, at some point you do something like:
`v := 0.9*v + 0.1*gradient` where `v` is the exponentially weighted average of your gradient `g`. If in a lot of successive iterations a same element of your `g` matrix remains 0, your `v` is quickly becoming very small and you hit dernormals.

So the problem, is why all those zeros ? In my case the culprit where the `ReLu` units which outputed a lot of zeros (if x<0 , relu(x) is zero). Because when `Relu` outputs zero on a given neurons the related weight has no effect it means the corresponding partial derivative will be zero in `g`. So it happened to me that in a lot of successive iterations that particular neuron was not fired.

To avoiding having zero activations (and derivatives), I used "leaky relu" so to have a very small derivative instead.

Another solution, is to use gradient clipping before applying your weighted average to threshold your gradients to a minimum value. Which is quite similar to what you did.